# Checking whether statement A implies statement B

Tags: logic

I would like to ask Mathematica "does `statement A` imply `statement B`?" and get a yes or no (`true` or `false`) answer whenever one exists.

I have entered the input `Reduce[ Implies[x>0 && y>0 , xy > 0] ]`. The output I was expecting was `true`. The output I actually get is `x <= 0 || y <= 0 || (y < 0 && x < 0) || (y > 0 && x > 0)`.

Could someone explain how I can get Mathematica to produce the desired result from the first paragraph?

Comment: Specifying `Reals` as domain seems to do the trick for dome reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mind the space between `x` and `y`!

```
Simplify@Reduce[
  Implies[x > 0 && y > 0, x y > 0]
  , {x, y}
  ]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: The lack of a space in my question was a typo (I had one in my Mathematica notebook). But it's the `Simplify` that indeed makes the difference. I'm embarrassed I didn't think of this. Thanks.